# Rotation cypher encryption doesn't encrypt

Tags: javascript

Today I'm having a problem with my rotation cypher encryption site. It is supposed to ask the type (ROT1, ROT2, ROT3, etc.) and the if you want to encrypt or decrypt. Then you have to enter the message and it would alert the outcome. Even though the decryption part does work, the encryption part doesn't. My code is as following:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ROT</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color.plus-names-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>       
    <script src="http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>



    <div id="choose_rot">

        <div>
            <div class="rot_button" id="1">ROT1</div>
            <div class="rot_button" id="2">ROT2</div>
            <div class="rot_button" id="3">ROT3</div>
            <div class="rot_button" id="4">ROT4</div>
            <div class="rot_button" id="5">ROT5</div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div class="rot_button" id="6">ROT6</div>
            <div class="rot_button" id="7">ROT7</div>
            <div class="rot_button" id="8">ROT8</div>
            <div class="rot_button" id="9">ROT9</div>
            <div class="rot_button" id="10">ROT10</div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div class="rot_button" id="11">ROT11</div>
            <div class="rot_button" id="12">ROT12</div>
            <div class="rot_button" id="13">ROT13</div>
            <div class="rot_button" id="14">ROT14</div>
            <div class="rot_button" id="15">ROT15</div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div class="rot_button" id="16">ROT16</div>
            <div class="rot_button" id="17">ROT17</div>
            <div class="rot_button" id="18">ROT18</div>
            <div class="rot_button" id="19">ROT19</div>
            <div class="rot_button" id="20">ROT20</div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div class="rot_button" id="21">ROT21</div>
            <div class="rot_button" id="22">ROT22</div>
            <div class="rot_button" id="23">ROT23</div>
            <div class="rot_button" id="24">ROT24</div>
            <div class="rot_button" id="25">ROT25</div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="encrypt_decrypt">
        <div class="encrypt_decrypt_button" id="decrypt">Encrypt</div>
        <div class="encrypt_decrypt_button" id="encrypt">Decrypt</div>
    </div>

    <div id="message">
        <form id="form">
            Enter the message: <input type="text" name="message">
            <br>
            <input type="button" value="encrypt/decrypt" onClick="sendMessage(this.form)">
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body, html  {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#choose_rot {
    display: inline;
    padding: auto;
}

#encrypt_decrypt    {
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -20%;
    margin-top: -37.5px;
    width: 100%;
}

#message    {
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    width: 100%;
}

#form   {
    width: 15%;
    height: 75px;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 2.5%;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.rot_button, .encrypt_decrypt_button    {
    width: 15%;
    height: 75px;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 2.5%;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And the most important part, the Javascript/JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()    {

    $("#encrypt_decrypt, .encrypt_decrypt_button, #message").fadeOut(0);

    var rotation;
    var type;

    $(".rot_button").click(function()   {
        window.rotation = $(this).attr("id");

        $("#choose_rot, .rot_button").fadeOut("slow", function()    {
            $("#encrypt_decrypt, .encrypt_decrypt_button").fadeIn("slow");
        });
    });

    $(".encrypt_decrypt_button").click(function()   {
        window.type = $(this).attr("id");

        $("#encrypt_decrypt, .encrypt_decrypt_button").fadeOut("slow", function()   {
            $("#message").fadeIn("slow");
        });
    });

});

function sendMessage(form) {
            var message =   form.message.value;
            message.toLowerCase();
            var ascii_message = new Array();
            var ascii_encrypted_message = new Array();
            var encrypted_message = new Array();

            for (i=0;i < message.length; i++) {

                ascii_message[i] =  message.charCodeAt(i);

            }

            for (i=0;i < message.length; i++) {

                if (    (ascii_message[i] >= 97)    &&  (ascii_message[i] <= 122)   )   {

                    if (type == "decrypt")  {

                        var new_message = ascii_message[i] + rotation;

                        if (new_message > 122)  {
                            new_message = new_message - 26;

                            ascii_encrypted_message[i] = new_message;

                            encrypted_message[i] =  String.fromCharCode(ascii_encrypted_message[i]);
                            alert( encrypted_message.join("") );
                        }

                        else    {
                            ascii_encrypted_message[i] = new_message;

                            encrypted_message[i] =  String.fromCharCode(ascii_encrypted_message[i]);
                            alert( encrypted_message.join("") );
                        }



                    }

                    else if (type == "encrypt") {
                        var new_message = ascii_message[i] - rotation;

                        if (new_message < 97)   {
                            new_message = new_message + 26;

                            ascii_encrypted_message[i] = new_message;

                            encrypted_message[i] =  String.fromCharCode(ascii_encrypted_message[i]);
                            alert( encrypted_message.join("") );
                        }

                        else    {
                            ascii_encrypted_message[i] = new_message;

                            encrypted_message[i] =  String.fromCharCode(ascii_encrypted_message[i]);
                            alert( encrypted_message.join("") );
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    alert("HELLO!");
                }
            }

        }
```

Could anyone perhaps help me solving this problem, the encrypt part is almost identical to the decrypt part. The only difference is the minus between the **ascii_message[i]** and the **rotation**.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YRwwY/1/

Comment: Note you've set the `id` for your Encrypt & Decrypt buttons wrong.

Comment: More than 70% of the content supplied ehre is irrelevant to the question - having a go at solving the problem yourself should be your first step before posting here. Both as a pre-requisite for addressing the problem yourself and for asking for help is to remove everything but the bare minimum necessary to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason one is working while the other one is not is in the usage of the "+" and "-" operators. Ascii_message[i] is a number, while rotation is a string. I would suggest changing the line to

```
var new_message = ascii_message[i] + parseInt(rotation);
```

so that you are adding two numbers, which should work fine. See: http://jsfiddle.net/YRwwY/2/